# Import csv file content to SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, entity-framework

I have an Excel file on my desktop, and I would like to use C# to insert Excel content to SQL Server, how sould I do? (use Entity Framework and console to complete it)

I use windows application(.NET Framework) and use code first to build my model.
Now I had build the table in SQL Server but I'm not sure how to read Excel file from desktop and insert data in excel file to SQL Server.

I just find Excel file from desktop then I don't know what should I do for next step.

```
 string path = @"\Users\chun0\Downloads\filename.csv";
 string input = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Could anyone help me?
Thank you all so much.

Comment: FYI : `filename.csv`. This is not excel file. It is just comma separated value text file

Comment: How many rows are in the csv? Maybe load it into a datatable then insert into sql server from there?

Comment: Also if this is a one off process then use SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio to Import the csv file ..

Comment: split this process into a few steps: 1) read the file line-by-line and 2) split the line into fields (I hope you know the fields to expect). Then 3) use those fields to insert one record into the database.

Comment: If you're attempting to read CSV files "line by line" then you're doing it wrong. Ignore any code samples or tutorials that offer to handle them that way. The CSV file format can split fields across multiple lines, it is best handled by a character-oriented state machine. There are plenty of well-supported Delimited Text File reading libraries for just about every language. Ref: [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your reply. There are five rows and over thousand column in csv file. And I tried to use code to import these data in to SQL server. So I should load into a datatable first? Then insert into SQL server?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thank you！I will try it. If I would like to insert into SQL server, I need to use List or other ways?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for your reply. I read Ref. and think about it. So I need to use character to insert into SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

This is, step by step, explanation of doing just what you ask, if I got it correct. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-excel-data-to-database-using-Asp-Net-mvc-entity-frame/